# Authorizing users on an on-premise service from SharePoint Online intranet

Tags: sharepoint-online, authentication, provider-hosted-app, authorization

I'm reading up on SharePoint Online as a candidate for our upcoming intranet, and have a couple of questions.

Let's say I need our users to access some on-premise data, and I write a provider based SharePoint add-in (which run on an on-premise server). The add-in require users to be authorized before serving them the data. What's best practice when it comes to authenticating and authorizing the users - could the client side of my add-in reuse some SSO/OAuth token or something from the SharePoint Online session, and pass this token on to the server-side my add-inn, and my server-side add-in (or preferably some firewall type of software in front of my sevice) could then authorize users based on this token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work if you use AzureAD as your SSO provider for the on-prem app.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Using AzureAD as an SSO provider for the on-prem app is only a matter of configuration, I assume - as long as my on-prem app has network access to AzureAD, and I set up things such as certificates and stuff, this should be pretty straight forward?

Comment: Correct, it is basically setting up ADFS, but using AzureAD instead of your own ADFS servers.  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/sharepoint-on-premises-tutorial